# Launch docker container from power shell fail, unexpected behavior?

Tags: powershell, docker, environment-variables, docker-for-windows, docker-compose

I have created the following script in powershell for two objectives:

1. read from an .env file the setup of the local urls of my development environment and deploy them to the Windows hosts file.
2. take advantage of the file, and script and validate that the docker service is started/active and otherwise try to turn it on, after this, execute the command to raise the docker setup from a configuration yml file.

*this is my .env file (work well):*

```
LH_URL="lh-2"
LH_URL_HOST="127.0.0.1 www.${LH_URL}.dock ${LH_URL}.dock www.${LH_URL}.pma.dock ${LH_URL}.pma.dock"
```

*this is my .yml file (work well):*

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

*this is my script deploy.ps1:*

```
if (!
    (New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(
        [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
    )).IsInRole(
        [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
    )
) {
    Start-Process `
        -FilePath 'powershell' `
        -ArgumentList (
            '-File', $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Source, $args `
            | %{ $_ }
        ) `
        -Verb RunAs
    exit
}
[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$scriptDirectory = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Set-Location -Path $scriptDirectory
$envFilePath = Join-Path -Path $scriptDirectory -ChildPath ".env"

if (Test-Path $envFilePath) {
    Write-Host "`nFound the .env file in the following location: $((Get-Item -Path $envFilePath).FullName)"
    $envFileContent = Get-Content $envFilePath -Raw
    [System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary]$envVariables = @{}

    $envFileContent -split [Environment]::NewLine | ForEach-Object {
        $line = $_.Trim()
        if ($line -match '^([^#=]+)=(.*)$') {
            $envVariables[$Matches[1]] = $Matches[2]
        }
    }
    $envVariables.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($_.Key, $_.Value, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Environment Variables File not found."
    pause
    exit 1
}

if ([System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("LH_URL") -and [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("LH_URL_HOST")) {
    $lh_url = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("LH_URL")
    $lh_url_host = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("LH_URL_HOST")
    $resolved_url_host = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($lh_url_host)
    $resolved_url_host = $resolved_url_host -replace '"', ''
    $entry = "`n`n$resolved_url_host"
    $hostsFile = "${env:SystemRoot}\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
    $currentContent = Get-Content $hostsFile -Raw
    if ($currentContent -notlike "*$entry*") {
        Add-Content -Path $hostsFile -Value $entry
        Write-Host "The URLs were successfully added to the Host!!!"
    }else{
        Write-Host "No need to add URLs to the host!!!"
    }
    Write-Host "`nThe docker service is being validated and started if docker desktop is not open..."
    $serviceName = "com.docker.service"
    $dockerService = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
    if ($dockerService.Status -eq "Running") {
        Write-Host "The Docker service is running."
    } else {
        Start-Service -Name $serviceName
        Write-Host "The Docker service has been started."
    }
    Write-Host "`nStarting the unloading and construction of containers..."
    docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --force-recreate
    pause
}
else {
    Write-Host "LH_URL/LH_URL_HOST environment variables are not defined in the .env file"
    pause
    exit 1
}
```

The first part of the script forces execution privileges... everything works fine if I have docker desktop open and initialized, but if I stop the service of docker and run the script so that the part of the script validates and initializes the service I get the following message:

> Found the .env file in the following location: E:\Web\LH2\docker.env
> No need to add URLs to the host!!!
>
> The docker service is being validated and started if docker desktop is
> not open... The Docker service has been started.
>
> Starting the downloading of image and construction of containers... error during
> connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker
> client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Get
> "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.config-hash%22%3Atrue%2C%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker%22%3Atrue%7D%7D":
> open //./pipe/docker_engine: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo
> especificado. Presione Entrar para continuar...:

***note:** Some things come out in Spanish because the operating system is in Spanish.*

***Question:***
I don't find what is wrong in my script. like the service or something is missing.

***Update:***

Researching a little more about the topic and doing tests, I have been able to validate that despite having the docker desktop service, when running powershell it does not have access to the environment variable that tells it to connect through: `"tcp://localhost :2375"` that means that this: `$env:DOCKER_HOST` does not exist or is empty even though I have already enabled it from the same docker desktop menu. and restarted the PC.